# Typescript: type starting with a pipe

Tags: typescript

I recently ran into this typescript syntax:

```
type Foo = | 5 | 6;
```

Turns out that this does compile, to my surprise. Is there any significance to that first pipe character? Or is it functionally equivalent to:

```
type Foo = 5 | 6;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leading pipe characters are **ignored** in union type definitions to give developers more formatting freedom.

You can check [PR#12386](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12386) on the official TypeScript repository for more info.